# Django REST Framework nested relations without related names

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have some models that relates to `User`, but does not have a related name on user:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='+')

class ManyToOneModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='+')
```

I would like to make a serializer for `User`, which can have this as a nested resource.  Is there a way to specify what the queryset/object is?  This is an example of what I have - and it completly expectedly failes with `'User' object has no attribute 'registration'`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.Field()

    registration = RegistrationSerializer()
    many_to_one_model = ManyToOneModelSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'd need to manually query for the related objects and then construct the serializers by hand. You'd then construct the final representation and pass that as the `data` parameter to a `Response` object.

It seems like you're making life difficult though. If you just define the `related_name` on your related models you could use `ModelSerializer` (or `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`) and it would all *Just Work™*. — Is there some reason why you can't do this?

Comment: Can't do that because there are other apps that have the same name models... there are reasons for this that make sense.  Which methods should I be overriding to do this?